# X-axis not in order when using sns.relplot

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I made a line graph using sns relplot but it's not showing the x-axis in the correct order. Here is the figure:

```
#plot line graph
g=sns.relplot( 
           data=df_fig1,
           kind="line")
g.fig.suptitle("Exams", y=1.05)
g.set(xlabel="Months",
     ylabel="Exams (%)")
g.fig.set_size_inches(8,6)
for ax in g.axes.flat:
    ax.yaxis.set_major_locator(MultipleLocator(5))
plt.show()
plt.show()
```

[image]

The x-axis order should be Jan, feb,...oct, Nov. How can I fix the order? I already fixed the index order in the dataframe but it still doesn't show up correctly on the plot.

Here is what my data frame looks like:
[image]

Comment: The a is is ordered alphabetically. You can easily solve this do using month numbers. I do not know how replot treats alphanumeric data, but there is probably a keyword to avoid sorting

Comment: Set `sort=False`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code has been tested using seaborn 0.11.2.  A dataframe in ["wide form"](https://seaborn.pydata.org/tutorial/data_structure.html#long-form-vs-wide-form-data) is given and no `x=` nor `y=` is assigned. Therefore, the index is used for the x-axis and then each column gets plotted separately.

If needed, you can reorder the index via `df.reindex(...)` with the list in the desired order.

You also can set an explicit order, converting a string column into ['categorical'](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Categorical.html) via pandas:

```py
df["month"] = pd.Categorical(df["month"], months_ordered)`
```

Here is some example code to show how it can work. Note that in a [figure-level](https://seaborn.pydata.org/tutorial/function_overview.html#figure-level-vs-axes-level-functions) plot, the `figsize` is set via `height=` and `aspect=` of individual subplots.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'month': ['Apr', 'Aug', 'Dec', 'Feb', 'Jan', 'Jul', 'Jun', 'Mar', 'May', 'Nov', 'Oct', 'Sep'],
                   'exams_increased': np.random.randint(16, 40, 12),
                   'capture_increased': np.random.randint(16, 40, 12)})
df = df.set_index('month')

# reorder the index with the order given in list 'months_ordered'
months_ordered = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
df = df.reindex(months_ordered)
# relplot when given a dataframe in wide form, uses the index to define the order
g = sns.relplot(data=df,
                kind="line", height=8, aspect=6 / 8)
plt.show()
```

[image: sns.relplot with ordered x-axis]

Comment: That worked! Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

> Disclaimer: this is inaccurate

`sns.relplot` always sorts it's x-axis.
If you want to treat your x axis as categories, relplot is not the right tool.
`sns.catplot` has an order parameter which should fit your needs, but since it's made for categorized data, it does not have an option for a line graph.
You'll have to choose between a line graph and correctly ordered data.

Comment: Better yet would be to make a datetime variable and plot against that.

Comment: This is not accurate. Sorting is the default but it can be disabled, and relplot otherwise works fine with categories.

Comment: My bad. I misread a different thread and somehow interpreted it as relplot being the wrong tool for the job, because it has no option to disable x-axis sorting. Thanks for correcting me!

Comment: It's ok, it's nuanced: you can disable sorting, but what you can't do (but could with the categorical plots) is specify a particular order directly, rather than using the order in the dataframe, or the order of the category dtype.